# Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch) - SQL, Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

```
for _item in file_list:
    for col in cursor.execute("select column1,column2 from tbl"):
        if _item[0]==col.column1:
            #I also tried using a different cursor, still doesn't work
            var1 = cursor.execute("select column2 from tbl where column1=?", _item[0])
            for i in var1: var2 = i[0]
            try:
                cursor3.execute("insert into tbl(column2,column1,column3,column4) values (?,?,?,?)", (var1, _item[0],_item[1],_item[2]))
                cursor3.commit() 
            except IOError as error:
                print error
```

What i am trying to do is compare the values in a list and the ones from column1, if they match, get the value from column2 on the same row, then add a new line with the value from column2 but different values for the remaining ones.

But unfortunately it doesen't work the way i did it, when running the code above python throws the error:

```
Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')
```

In line:

```
for columnrow in cursor.execute("select column1,column2 from tbl")
```

Comment: The line which you say generates the error does not appear in your code sample. Also there appears to be a typo: I think `colum2` should be `column2`.

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed it

Comment: in case anyone faces this error and gets here. I was getting an error as i was closing the connection before fetching the rows from the cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is fine and should work per @ScottMorken's comment to this answer.

---

Old answer:
You need to retrieve the results of the query using, for example, `.fetchall()`
So instead of that line you could do:

```
for columnrow in cursor.execute("select column1,column2 from tbl").fetchall():
    ...
```

Comment: not according to https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started. On page see: "If you are going to process the rows one at a time, you can use the cursor itself as an iterator"